# Angular 2 custom control inside form, default value is [object Object]

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've a simple angular2 reactive form:

*formangular.component.html*

```html
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formDir.value)" [formGroup]="complexForm" #formDir="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <custom-input id="idCausaleRitenuta"
                  class="form-control"
                  label="Codice:"
                  formControlName="idCausaleRitenuta"
                  [(ngModel)]="idCausaleRitenuta"></custom-input>
    <div *ngIf="idCausaleRitenuta.invalid && (idCausaleRitenuta.dirty || idCausaleRitenuta.touched)"
         class="alert alert-danger">
........
```

the relative .ts file:

*formangular.component.ts*

```js
export class FormAngularComponent { 
get idCausaleRitenuta() { return this.complexForm.get('idCausaleRitenuta');}

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private ritenuteService: RitenuteService, private sharedService: SharedService) {
this.createForm();}

createForm() {
this.complexForm = this.fb.group({
  idCausaleRitenuta: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(4)])],
........
```

...And the custom-input control:

*custominput.component.ts*

```js
.................

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `<div>
              <label *ngIf="label" [attr.for]="identifier">{{label}}</label>
               <input [id]="identifier"
                      [type]="type"
                      [class]="class"
                      [placeholder]="placeholder"
                      [(ngModel)]="value"
                      (blur)="touch()" />
            </div>`,
.......
})

export class CustomInputComponent<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {
.........

  identifier = `custom-input-${identifier++}`;

  private innerValue: T;

  private changed = new Array<(value: T) => void>();
  private touched = new Array<() => void>();

  get value(): T {
    return this.innerValue;
  }
  set value(value: T) {
    if (this.innerValue !== value) {
      this.innerValue = value;
      this.changed.forEach(f => f(value));
    }
  }
  touch() {
    this.touched.forEach(f => f());
  }
  writeValue(value: T) {
    this.innerValue = value;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: (value: T) => void) {
    this.changed.push(fn);
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.touched.push(fn);
  }
}

let identifier = 0;
```

When I render the form, the value of the input inside the 'custom control' is  '[object Object]', can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make this call:

```
get idCausaleRitenuta() { return this.complexForm.get('idCausaleRitenuta');}
```

You are actually getting the [`FormControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) object (not the value of the form control).

You can access the `value` property of that control like this:

```
get idCausaleRitenuta() { return this.complexForm.get('idCausaleRitenuta').value;}
```

Comment: Work. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help -- to let others know your question has been answered, click the big check mark to "accept" the answer and consider clicking the up arrow to upvote if you thought it was a good answer :) Welcome to SO